# Jetty 9 support for TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, java, tls, jetty

I've been trying to get that A+ on the [SSL Server Test @ SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). However, I can't figure out how to pass the "downgrade attack prevention" test:

[image: TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV]

I'm running Jetty 9.3.0.v20150612 alongside OpenJDK 8, on Linux Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet).

```
hristo@test:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

I've read through and followed the instructions from [Jetty's SSL config documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html), and tried my best to edit the relevant XML config files. No matter what I try, I still see "No, TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV not supported".

I've enabled the `https` and `ssl` modules for Jetty by running this command:

```
$ java -jar start.jar --add-to-startd=https,ssl
INFO: ssl             initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.d/ssl.ini
INFO: https           initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.d/https.ini
INFO: Base directory was modified
```

I haven't modified the vanilla `jetty.xml` nor `jetty-https.xml` because I'm not sure what I need to change there. Here's what I have for my configs:

**start.ini**

```
# added this to the bottom of start.ini
# TLS configuration
-Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
```

**jetty-ssl-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<!-- ============================================================= -->
<!-- SSL ContextFactory configuration                              -->
<!-- ============================================================= -->
<Configure id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">

  <!-- ===================== -->
  <!-- other default configs -->
  <!-- ===================== -->

  <Set name="IncludeCipherSuites">
    <Array type="String">
      <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384</Item>
      <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</Item>
      <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384</Item>
      <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
      <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>

      <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384</Item>
      <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</Item>
      <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256</Item>
      <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>

      <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384</Item>
      <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</Item>
      <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256</Item>
      <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
      <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
  <Set name="IncludeProtocols">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
       <Item>TLSv1</Item>
       <Item>TLSv1.1</Item>
       <Item>TLSv1.2</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
  <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
    <Array type="String">
      <Item>SSL.*</Item>
      <Item>.*DES.*</Item>
      <Item>.*DSS.*</Item>
      <Item>.*KRB.*</Item>
      <Item>.*MD5.*</Item>
      <Item>.*NULL.*</Item>
      <Item>.*RC4.*</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
  <Set name="ExcludeProtocols">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
       <Item>SSL</Item>
       <Item>SSLv2</Item>
       <Item>SSLv2Hello</Item>
       <Item>SSLv3</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
  <Set name="renegotiationAllowed" type="boolean">false</Set>
  <Set name="useCipherSuitesOrder"><Property name="jetty.sslContext.useCipherSuitesOrder" default="true"/></Set>
</Configure>
```

What else am I missing? Do I need to configure Jetty some more? Do I need to configure Java 8 somehow? Do I need to modify some special Ubuntu configs?

Comment: You could put your Jetty instance behind [HAProxy](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/http2-configuring-haproxy.html) and let the latter handle TLS for you.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply not implemented in Java yet – it is planned for Java 9 though.

You can follow [#JDK-8061798](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061798) for updates.

Comment: I know that Jetty uses Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) by default. Do you know if it's possible to get Jetty to use OpenSSL instead (which supports the TLS_FALLBACK_SCV cipher suite)?